# Linked in social share, Dynamic path not working

Tags: linkedin-api, share

Hello acttually im creating social share for my company, 'facebook, whatsapp, twitter and linkedin' it working fine for 3 of them, only linked not working

heres how i create:

```
<button class"btnshare" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url='+window.location.href)"><img src="/content/dam/icon/linkedin-24.png"></button>
```

and return 
[image]

please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the same it was working fine for me, did you try after sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending `GET` parameters to a website, you need to escape them.  You want `encodeURIComponent()`, like so...

```js
var site = "http://example.com";
var shareurl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(site);

window.open(shareurl);

console.log("Shared Link: " + shareurl);
```

Notice how the URL becomes `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`, and not `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://example.com`.  This is important, because it is how the browser distinguishes between a command given by the user (i.e. `http://`) and data sent to a website (i.e. `name=fred`).

If your site is still having trouble, then try inspecting it with the **[LinkedIn Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/)**.  This little tool will tell everything that is taken into consideration when deciding how to generate the preview page when sharing.